How this kind of lvm setup happened and how to fix this?
im new in linux and i encounter this kind of setup
lsblk
sdb                              8:16   0    3T  0 disk 
|-sdb1                           8:17   0  200G  0 part 
| `-APP-app1               253:3    0  700G  0 lvm  /app1
|-sdb2                           8:18   0  800G  0 part 
| `-DATA-logs               253:2    0  800G  0 lvm  /logs
`-sdb3                           8:19   0  500G  0 part 
  `-APP-app1                 253:3    0  700G  0 lvm  /app1

lvs
LV              VG     Attr       LSize     Devices         
  app1          APP   -wi-ao----  699.99g   /dev/sdb1(0)                                                           
  app1          APP   -wi-ao----  699.99g   /dev/sdb3(0)                                                                  

as you can see the output of lsblk and lvs shows 2 app1 lv, (its the same vg and lv but not sure why it shows 2)
How did this happened and how to fix this? Also what is the effect of this kind of setup?

Volume group APP spans two physical volumes. Volume group DATA also exists. Your output is truncated, because at least DATA/logs should also appear in lvs output.
The sdb partitions you show are all on the same disk.
Multiple PVs, VGs, LVs, is absolutely a thing LVM can do. Its why LVM was invented in the first place. However, you may prefer simpler setups of one PV (and perhaps one disk/LUN) per VG.
If the intent of the different LVs is to separate APP and DATA onto different physical disks, it fails to do so. Separate disks is desirable if you wish to clone those separately. Or manage the size separately. Or for very high availability environments, such as databases where logs are stored separately.
Unlikely, but ask whomever set this up if they intended to use any fancy features like LVM mirroring. Which is a RAID 1 but at the LVM level. There is no m for mirroring flag in the lvs output, so probably not.
And possibly the most likely, the partitioning scheme did not fit the size required. PV sdb3 was partitioned and added later, and existing LV app1 extended into it.
If you can successfully manage this storage to meet the needs, nothing is broken and needs fixing.
However during a storage migration, you can move PVs around however you like, while keeping storage online and in use.  Such as making the LV continuous.  Add new disk (partition) of at least the 1400 GB (the total LV size) or whatever you require from capacity planning.  vgextend this onto the existing APP VG.  Then move it:  pvmove --lv app1  /dev/sdb1 /dev/sdb3
